# Is it safe to drink Lipton green tea (tea bag) that has a production date of November 2018?

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime

I have Lipton green tea that has a production date: October 2018. The box has 4 plastic bags, each contain 20 tea bags inside. Haven't open any of it...Is it safe to consume? If yes, when is the best time to consume a green tea? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Does the packaging have an expiry (or best before) date printed on it? If yes, what does it say?

Comment: No expiration date printed but production date which is October 24, 2018

Comment: Does it atleast say "use within x years of manufacture"?!!! Surprising. Even if the actual tea leaves are safe, the packaging material may have a safe to use by time.

Comment: It doesn't say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is safe,

At worse it'll not have the freshest taste possible, but it will be OK.

Comment: Seeing as you are pouring boiling hot water on it that should be enough to kill most micro organisms.

Comment: In my experience, most teas and infusions lose flavour very slowly, and are still fine to drink if unopened even after many years.  (And in this case, with a package made <3 years ago, I expect it's still well within any ‘use by’ date anyway.)